# Xamarin Colors Causing Build Errors

Tags: android, styles, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have an android application built with Xamarin Studio.  I added a file named colors.xml to the Resources/values folder.  The contents were:

```
<resources>
    <color name="ViewBackgroundColor">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

To that, I was following [this approach](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) to define and use it; however, I was trying to apply it to the view's root element (found that resource elsewhere on SO, don't have exact link).  So I applied it to the view by adding `android:background="@color/ViewBackgroundColor"` attribute to the root element.  However, this generates a build error that @color/ViewBackgroundColor isn't a value.  is anybody else having this issue and is there a resolution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To reference that color, you must use all lowercase letters.

So

```
android:background="@color/viewbackgroundcolor"
```

This is because the Xamarin tools lowercases all names to be compliant with the rules Android has for resource names.

Answer (score 1):

Is also important to set "Build Action" (with mouse right button on file color.xml)  as AndroidResource.